# Can someone recommend a recent book on cytoskeletal proteins? Most preferably similar to "Guidebook to the Cytoskeletal and Motor Proteins" from 1998

Tags: book-recommendation, cytoskeleton

As in the question, I'm looking for such a book, that will give an overview of the topic from general perspective, with some "branching ideas", and references to literature about them. As for the book I mentioned, I accesed some fragments of it by uni network, and I hope it can serve as a reference of what I'm looking for.